# Spring WebFlux with socket.io capabilities

Tags: socket.io, spring-webflux, spring-websocket, rsocket

I'm playing around with [Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux) and how to do async I/O in Java but it seems I need to set up a lot of boilerplates for managing websockets. For example, very common operations need to be re-implemented by hand:

- websocket connect/disconnect
- message broadcasting (to a list or all connected sockets)
- gathering websockets in rooms

Is there any library (mature or in-development) to abstract complexity of managing websockets with
Spring WebFlux ? I'm looking for similar capabilities/API of the wonderful [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

I took a (very brief) look at [RSocket](https://rsocket.io/), it looks promising but still at a lower-level than socket.io for NodeJS.

Any help/guidelines would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find anything that suited your needs? Looking into a websocket implementation with Springboot and not sure if I should go with Spring Web Socket or a java socket.io implementation https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio-demo

Comment: In the end, I used RSocket. It brings some abstraction over WebFlux but not quite as much as socket.io. I guess it's simply because reactive programming is less mature within the Java ecosytem. It has a spring-boot starter project which autoconfigures a bunch of thing for you so it's pretty simple to get started. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Let me know you thoughts on this and on whatever you decide to go with, I'm always interested in having another look from another dev

Comment: Trying to keep it simple as possible for my use case. Is going reactive for websockets recommended? I see websockets mentioned in the Spring docs for both Web and Flux, and now feel I'm at a crossroads haha. The reactive docs do mention RSocket support with a section on that, so it seems like your choice is well supported by Spring. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/reference/html/web-reactive.html#rsocket